# convert a string to a bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-core, boolean

I have a string that can be either "0" or "1", and it is guaranteed that it won't be anything else.

So the question is: what's the best, simplest and most elegant way to convert this to a bool?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Furthermore please learn how to create a [mcve]. Lastly, don't forget to tell us what language you're programming in, by adding it as a tag when you edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Beyond the above link for how to create a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example, the answer to your question is completely dependent upon what language you are using and you haven't mentioned that at all.  Even just adding that would allow someone to quickly and easily help you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool b = str == "1";
```

The above code will return true if str is 1 and false if str is 0 or null.

Answer (score 0):

Dependant on the language you are using, a simple IF would get the job done.

```
if(string == '1'){
bool = true;
} else {
bool = false;
}
```

Comment: It is also doing the same job but that consists single line. Hence we can achieve code minimization.

Comment: `string == '1'` already returns a bool in most languages. Why add a whole if-else for nothing?